# Devexpress WPF tile long press open menu click navigate

Tags: c#, wpf, menu, click, tile

I have a TileLayoutControl that generates tiles from itessource

```
<dxlc:TileLayoutControl ItemsSource="{Binding ProductsCategories}" TileClick="ProductsCategories_TileClick">
            <dxlc:TileLayoutControl.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="dxlc:Tile">
                    <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ContextMenu>
                                <MenuItem Header="TestItem"/>
                            </ContextMenu>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="100"/>
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"/>
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20" />
                    <Setter Property="Uid" Value="{Binding wcatsn}" />
                    <Setter Property="Header"  Value="{Binding}" />
                    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding wcatdescrEL}" Foreground="Black" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" FontSize="12"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseDown" Handler="Tile_PreviewMouseDown" />
                </Style>
                <Style TargetType="dxlc:TileGroupHeader">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000" />
                </Style>
            </dxlc:TileLayoutControl.Resources>
        </dxlc:TileLayoutControl>
```

and I have a TileClick event that navigates my main frame (in witch the TileLayoutControl is into) to an other page.

Now I also want to add an event so when i press a tile and keep it down after 5 seconds the context menu of the tile becomes enabled.

I tried to achieve this with a PreviewMouseDown event but that way my TileClick event is not working. Whatever I do only the PreviewMouseDown event is getting triggered.

```
private System.Threading.AutoResetEvent _stopTrigger;

    private void Tile_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedTile = sender as DevExpress.Xpf.LayoutControl.Tile;
        string ButtonToProductsCategoriesViewEnabled = ButtonToProductsCategoriesView.Visibility.ToString();


        if (ButtonToProductsCategoriesViewEnabled != "Visible")
        {
            if (this._stopTrigger == null)
            {
                this._stopTrigger = new System.Threading.AutoResetEvent(false);
            }

            if (!this._stopTrigger.WaitOne(5000))
            {
                (selectedTile).ContextMenu.IsEnabled = true;
                (selectedTile).ContextMenu.PlacementTarget = (selectedTile);
                (selectedTile).ContextMenu.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Bottom;
                (selectedTile).ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

OK i found it here is the code for anyone who might have the same problem

XAML CS Code:

```
//Event for checking if the MouseUp event triggered
    private System.Threading.AutoResetEvent _stopTrigger;

    private void Tile_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedTile = sender as DevExpress.Xpf.LayoutControl.Tile;
        string ButtonToProductsCategoriesViewEnabled = ButtonToProductsCategoriesView.Visibility.ToString();
        int wcatpsn = Convert.ToInt32(selectedTile.Uid);

        App.Current.Properties["selectedTile_wcatpsn"] = wcatpsn;
        App.Current.Properties["selectedTile"] = selectedTile;

        if (ButtonToProductsCategoriesViewEnabled != "Visible")
        {
            if (this._stopTrigger == null)
            {
                this._stopTrigger = new System.Threading.AutoResetEvent(false);

            }

            Action openMenuProcess = new Action(this.OpenMenuAfterTime);

            //Executes openMenuProcess on a differnet thread
            openMenuProcess.BeginInvoke(null, null);
        }
    }

    private void Tile_PreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this._stopTrigger != null)
        {
            // Sends the signal to the ShowPopupAfterTime that it should NOT display the pop up
            // IIt will make WaitOne return true and not go into the if statement
            this._stopTrigger.Set();
        }

        //Get selected Tile
        var selectedTile = sender as DevExpress.Xpf.LayoutControl.Tile;
        int wcatpsn = Convert.ToInt32(selectedTile.Uid);

        string connString = App.Current.Properties["connString"].ToString();

        using (TabletEntities db =
        new TabletEntities(connString))
        {
            List<Get_ProductsCategories_sp_Result> ProductsSubCategoriesList = db.Get_ProductsCategories_sp(wcatpsn).ToList<Get_ProductsCategories_sp_Result>();

            //Checks for sub categories
            if (ProductsSubCategoriesList.Count != 0)
            {
                //If there are sub categories navigates to ProductsCategoriesPage
                var MainFrame = DevExpress.Xpf.Core.Native.LayoutHelper.FindParentObject<NavigationFrame>(this);
                ProductsCategoriesView ProductsCategoriesPage = new ProductsCategoriesView();
                MainFrame.Navigate(ProductsCategoriesPage, wcatpsn);

                App.Current.Properties["ButtonToProductsCategoriesView"] = "active";
            }
            else
            {
                App.Current.Properties["ProductsSubCategories_wcatpsn"] = wcatpsn;

                //If there arent sub categories navigates to ProductsPage
                var MainFrame = DevExpress.Xpf.Core.Native.LayoutHelper.FindParentObject<NavigationFrame>(this);
                ProductsView ProductsPage = new ProductsView();
                MainFrame.Navigate(ProductsPage, wcatpsn);
            }
        }
    }

    //Runs timer and Enables ContextMenu after 2 seconds
    private void OpenMenuAfterTime()
    {
        // Will enter the if after 2 seconds
        if (!this._stopTrigger.WaitOne(2000))
        {

            var selectedTile = App.Current.Properties["selectedTile"] as DevExpress.Xpf.LayoutControl.Tile;

             TileLayoutControlProductsCategories.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                (selectedTile).ContextMenu.IsEnabled = true;
                (selectedTile).ContextMenu.PlacementTarget = (selectedTile);
                (selectedTile).ContextMenu.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Bottom;
                (selectedTile).ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;

            }));
        }
    }
```

XAML Code:

```
<dxlc:TileLayoutControl x:Name="TileLayoutControlProductsCategories" ItemsSource="{Binding ProductsCategories}" ShowLayerSeparators="True" AllowItemMoving="False" Padding="40,60,40,10" Margin="0,-20,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <dxlc:TileLayoutControl.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="dxlc:Tile">
                    <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ContextMenu>
                                <MenuItem Header="Παρουσιαση όλων των προιόντων"/>
                                <MenuItem Header="Παρουσιαση υποκατηγοριών"/>
                            </ContextMenu>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="100"/>
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"/>
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20" />
                    <Setter Property="Uid" Value="{Binding wcatsn}" />
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid Background="DarkGray">

                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Header"  Value="{Binding}" />
                    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding wcatdescrEL}" Foreground="Black" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" FontSize="12"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseDown" Handler="Tile_PreviewMouseDown" />
                    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseUp" Handler="Tile_PreviewMouseUp" />
                </Style>
                <Style TargetType="dxlc:TileGroupHeader">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000" />
                </Style>
            </dxlc:TileLayoutControl.Resources>
        </dxlc:TileLayoutControl>
```